# Is there any way of defining string constants that will be shared by Javascript source and another language source?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing code that bridges between JavaScript and Objective-C, the mechanism for this is done using proprietary schemes in URLs i.e.

function someJavaScriptFunction {
       callObjectiveC(@"some-scheme://someActionA");
}

Instead of hardcoding "some-scheme" and "someActionA" in either the Javascript source or the Objective-C source I'd like if possible to do the equivalent of something like #include constants for this.

Is there anyway this could be done such that the file containing the constants could be shared and the equivalent of #included into both the objective-c source files and the javascript source files?

Comment: Maybe have a file that will be opened and read by Objective C and ajax-ed from the localhost by JS?